# SetMargin method not working when 2nd page starts itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am displaying some content in a pdf file with a Header and footer by implementing `OnStartPage` and `OnEndPage` Methods.

The data which is printing in this pdf file is dynamic i.e sometimes it could be on one page and sometimes could go on 2 or more pages.

The problem is I Set the Margins of the page using `setMargins` method , this setmargin method is working fine only for the 1st page while on other pages , it's generating many more margins .

Here is my code :

this is where I call the method to generate pdf :

```
disclaimer.SetMargins(10, 10, 70,80);
disclaimer.Open();
GenerateQuotPDF getpdf = new GenerateQuotPDF();
disclaimer = getpdf.GetPDFparams(disclaimer,quote_num, Session["empcd"].ToString(),txt_contactperson.Text,txt_contact1.Text,txt_company.Text,txt_address.Text,ddl_gene_desc.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_canopy.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_gene_type.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_rentalamount.Text,txt_hours.Text,txt_variable.Text,ddl_terms.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_remarks.Text,txt_technical.Text);
disclaimer.Close();
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Please Help me

Comment: I don't see any header or footer related code in your *"method to generate pdf"*. Furthermore *"this setmargin method is working fine only for the 1st page while on other pages , it's generating many more margins"*: I don't see any margin related code in your method either. And what do you mean by *"many more margins"*?

Comment: In your first two lines of code you appear to be working with a `PdfDocument`. On your fourth line you pass that object to a method of your own and that method then returns something that you are overwriting your first object with. I'm assuming you are essentially returning the `disclaimer` object and writing it on top of itself but that's a really weird way to do it.